# Symfony 3.2 No mapping file found

Tags: php, symfony

I'm a beginner in Symfony and I'm trying to find a solution for this error .
So I 've been working on developing a backoffice from scratch I haven't used `FosUserBundle` nor have I used any other pre-built bundle.

I created two entities(`Admin`, `User`) that extend from an entity `Person` in  one `Bundle`, I finished the registration form the login and some of the functionalities that an administrator can execute in his backoffice then I moved to generating a third entity which is FAQ entity.

Things were good until I created the FAQ entity. Now when I try to login to the admin account it generates an error that says

> No mapping file found named 'Admin.orm.yml' for class
>   'project\HelloBundle\Entity\Admin'.

Would anyone please help me solve this problem. I tried to fix it, I've made some researches but with 0 success.

Someone please help me.

Comment: can u show sample code ?

Comment: Hello KPK..thank you for your answer..actually i solved it..all i had to do was to write manually the Admin.orm.yml file under src/Resources/doctrine..i wonder if it could have been generated after running a certain command ..and i really can't figure out why this error wasn't generated before..as i said everything was working perfectly until i added a new entity.

Comment: But i'm facing another problem concerning the logging in process..
I'm pretty sure i have something crucial missing in the security.yml file or may be in the methodsthat check the authentification of the admin.

Comment: i can't find a way to make the security system take into  consideration the role of the admin when logging in via database..i have two roles {ROLE_ADMIN ,ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN}

Comment: i followed the symfony documentation more specifically the "How to Load Security Users from the Database (the Entity Provider)" chapter.But still it's not working 
i would be more than gratefull if someone helped me.

Comment: @KPK any ideas ?